# Facing this issue when i am trying to open firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using below selenium Code to launch the Firefox browser

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Pooja\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.32.0-win-aarch64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driverF = new FirefoxDriver();
```

But I am getting the below issue in console.

```
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-5IHSH7G', ip: '192.168.2.199'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at NFT_SELENIUM.NFT_selenium_testcases.main(NFT_selenium_testcases.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.7.1', revision: 'c6795baf1a3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium version 4.7.2 then there is no need of System.setProperty.
You need to give only : WebDriver driverF=new FirefoxDriver();